# Gogs.io running on subdomain with port

Tags: apache, web, subdomain, gogs

I'm trying to run Gogs.io on an apache webserver along with a standard website, and I'm trying to have Gogs.io used on a subdomain rather than using my standard domain with a port.

Gogs.io runs on port 3000, and I want the url to be

`http://gogs.example.net/`

Rather than

`http://example.net:3000/`

Both my public IP with port and `example.net:3000` work, but when trying to use `gogs.example.net`, I always get an AT&T DNS Error Assist page. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I had it working earlier until I tried to change the name of the subdomain in my apache config, but I changed it back when I started having issues, to no luck.

Here is my Apache config for the page:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName gogs.example.net
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://example.net:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://example.net:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

This may be impossible, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding an A record to my domain

`A Record: git  ->  111.222.333.444`

As well as modified the VirtualHost settings to include the subdomain in the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName gogs.example.net
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://git.example.net:3000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://git.example.net:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```